# Persistent device identifier even after app gets uninstalled

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, udid, identification

In my iPhone/iPad app's use case, there is a voting system and one device can send its vote once to the server. Therefore my server needs to identify user's device. I don't want the user to register an account because that makes the app complicate. However, I couldn't find a solution that works.

- UDID is deprecated
- I presume getting MAC address will get your app rejected by the app review process
- I tried creating my own UUID using `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` and then storing it using `NSUserDefaults`, but the settings disappear if the user uninstalls the app
- `identifierForVendor` is also reset when the user uninstalls the app
- I considered `advertisingIdentifier` but because I'm not using it for advertisement, I presume it will also be rejected by the app review process

I'm not asking for a bulletproof solution in every situation. Just a solution that works even if the user uninstalls the app. Because I can generate my own UUID, I guess my question boils down to: How I can save data for the app that survives app uninstallation?

However if any of you have other approach, please feel free to inform me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the UUID into the keychain.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Tried SFHFKeychainUtils and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks. Can view the sample source code at following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device