# device identifierForVendor UUIDString different for release and test on same device

Tags: ios, xcode, udid

I use [[device identifierForVendor] UUIDString] to return the udid.

When I test with a build using my iPad the value returned is different to when
I run using the app when downloaded from the App Store.

I am using the same device, yet the udid differs?

I have only noticed this since updating to Xcode 6.1.

Is there a setting in Xcode that determines this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist it yourself as it will change when a user uninstalls/re installs the app.  So in your case when you download it from the Appstore its a new install and the identifier will have changed

[How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device)