# Cordova-IOS How to get iPhone UUID or alternative identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am working on a Cordova based application and I need to identify the device for security reasons before send any requests to the server side

But as you may know Apple now forbidden any way to identify the device .

I have tried many plugins but it seems working only on android , on IOS it just identify the app not the device I also tried native objective C code like

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]
```

but it also changed on removing the app and reinstall it

Any suggestion on how to identify the iPhone either with UDID or IMEI or any other alternative

Comment: It is not possible to read the original UUID from iOS devices.

Comment: The point mentioned by Joerg is very important. You can no longer get a specific device identifier which is persistent across reinstalls and different apps. You have to use the vendor identifier which *can* be changed by the user. You should not try to find a way to get something like a real UUID because that would violence your users privacy. If Apple would notice, you would probably even be kicked out of app store.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#deviceuuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reming Hsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971946/reming-hsu)  was right the idea of saving any UDID even if it was for the app in the keychain then reuse it was very effective and here is the full code

```
 NSString *myUUID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]    UUIDString];
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"myApp" accessGroup:nil];
if ([[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] length]) {

    NSString *imeiFromK = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

}
else {

    [keychainItem setObject:myUUID forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep identifierForVendor or custom UUID in KeyChain.

It won't change on removing the app and reinstall it.

See:
[How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device%3E)

### More..

I am not working with Cordova, but i know how hybrid app working.

1. Create iOS native method to manager(get、set、remove) KeyChain.
2. Create iOS native method to create UUID.
3. Let Cordova work with native method: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html

If you don't want to do it yourself, use the plugins i found:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.crypho.plugins.securestorage
or
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.shazron.cordova.plugin.keychainutil

But you should check if they are working.

Comment: tell him how to do this with cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the standard `cordova-plugin-device` which has the `device.uuid` method and works on Android and IOS?

See: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#deviceuuid

> Get the device's Universally Unique Identifier (UUID).
>
> `var string = device.uuid;`

Comment: it also returns an unique identifier per application not per device which mean when user remove the app and install it again it generate another UUID