# Does two device will have the same 'UUID'

Tags: ios, ios7, uuid, uniqueidentifier, uidevice

In my iOS app, I have to restrict the user to use iOS app per device. To do this I found a solution that we can use the [identifierForVendor method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878670) of `UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)` which will generate a unique ID to uniquely identify an app on a device. (Here, I am not using `UDID (Unique Device Identifier)` because Apple rejects apps if the app uses UDID).

So my question as is there any possibilities that the two devices will have the same `UUID`. any idea?

**EDIT 1:**

I have one more doubt as if I installed the same app on different two devices and save its `UUID` string into the device `KeyChain`. Both devices have same `iCloud` account. Now while doing `iCloud` sync for this two devices, is one my device `KeyChain` will gets overwritten?

**EDIT 2:**

I have found answer for EDIT 1 as 'Yes, through `iCloud Keychain`, the `keychain` would be synced to another one of my devices, and I’d get the same device identifier [from here](http://tinymission.com/post/ios-identifierforvendor-frequently-changing) and from below answer too'

For the item to be synced with `iCloud keychain`, I’d need to explicitly set the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute. Using the `SecItem` API, we can set this attribute while adding a keychain item.

Is there any tutorial how to add item in `Keychain` (Without third party libraries)?

Comment: hey you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device, it solves the problem

Comment: Hi Gekb, Thanks for your comment. In the link of your question, I have asked you whether you are able to find any solution. Can you please help me.

Comment: Yes the answer in my question solves the issue, also you can clear your doubt about iCloud keychain at :https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204085

Device keychain is different and iCloud Keychain is different as per my understanding. I'm just comparing our Mac OS keychain, we have System,login,Local items etc in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Two device does not have the same `UUID`. I am 100% Sure about it. So go with `identifierForVendor` method.

But, The `UUID` may be changed when you reinstall the the application in your device (If there is not other application for the same vendor).

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

**EDIT**

**YOUR QUESTION**

I have one more doubt as if I installed the same app on different two devices and save its UUID string into the device KeyChain. Both devices have same iCloud account. Now while doing iCloud sync for this two devices, is one my device KeyChain will gets overwritten?

**ANSWER**

YES. Your keychain will gets overwritten. So you have same UUID for both 2 devices.

Comment: #V.J. Thank you for your answer. Can you please check my edited question too.

Answer (score 1):

I thought is NO!

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.