# Is the capacitor device info uuid unique across all devices?

Tags: android, ios, capacitor

For a app we are building we would like users to join a certain event just by clicking a link.
We have deeplinking working so we can immediately connect the event to the device. By making a API call to our server and store these ID's.

With this call we can get this ID.

But what need to be sue about is, is whether this uuid is really unique across all devices?

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Device } = Plugins;

const info = await Device.getInfo();
console.log(info);

// Example output:
{
  "diskFree": 12228108288,
  "appVersion": "1.0.2",
  "appBuild": "123",
  "appId": "com.capacitorjs.myapp",
  "appName": "MyApp",
  "operatingSystem": "ios",
  "osVersion": "11.2",
  "platform": "ios",
  "memUsed": 93851648,
  "diskTotal": 499054952448,
  "model": "iPhone",
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "uuid": "84AE7AA1-7000-4696-8A74-4FD588A4A5C7",
  "isVirtual":true
}
```

At the documentation it states the following:
`The UUID of the device as available to the app. This identifier may change on modern mobile platforms that only allow per-app install UUIDs.`

But that does not make clear if it's unique across all devices.
So does anyone know if the uuid above is really unique across all devices?

**Edit**
I think I found my answer, in case their method and this one will return the same result:
[Does two device will have the same 'UUID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020075/does-two-device-will-have-the-same-uuid)

Comment: Hello Tim, UUID always attached with device info so two devices won't have same UUID.