# How to find UDID for ios9

Tags: ios9, udid

Since iOS 7 it's impossible to get UDID directly on an Apple iOS device.

i know apple suggests for using UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString. but it changes every time after uninstalling the app.

i want to send GCM to the users, and per user, there are two to three ios devices. so for identifying the devices uniquely i want UDID.

for ex. if user has two devices

in my server database i'm storing it like this

userID->>> abc@xyz.com

GCMID->>> {UDIDForDevice1:GCMTokenForDevice1,UDIDForDevice2:GCMTOkenForDevice2}

Comment: Vendor specific UDID doesn't necessarily change after uninstalling the app.  Why do you need the UDID and why doesn't vendor specific ID work for you?

Comment: i want to send GCM to the users, and per user, there are two to three ios devices. so for identifying the devices uniquely i want UDID.

Comment: So, your *actual* question is how to identify unique devices across a single user?  Because `vendorSpecificId` does that.

Comment: do you have any ideas for that? @nhgrif

Comment: @nhgrif I think you mean `UIDevice.identifierForVendor`

Comment: UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString changes every time when i re install the app. so i can't use it

Comment: You need to update your question and clarify exactly what you do need rather than asking people to speculate on how something else works.

Comment: @nhgrif i updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really uniquely identify a device, store a UUID on the keychain. See [How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device).

For GCM you should probably use the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id) instead of inventing your own identification format.

---

For the original question, the site `www.easy-udid.com` uses [**Over-the-Air Profile Delivery and Configuration**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH1-SW1) to obtain the UDID and other device information.

The "Get my UDID" button links to a `qilin.en.mobileconfig` file, which is a [Configuration Profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206) plist file with the following content:

```
{
  "PayloadType":"Profile Service",
  "PayloadContent":{
    "DeviceAttributes":[
      "UDID",
      "VERSION",
      "PRODUCT",
      "SERIAL"
    ],
    "URL":"http://www.easy-udid.com/retrieve.php"
  },
  ...
}
```

When the user installs the profile, the phone will send the UDID, version, product and serial number while opening the provided URL (`http://www.easy-udid.com/retrieve.php`). The server can then display the result to the user.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html for some sample responses.

Comment: (But I doubt why you need a permanent ID for cloud messaging)........... because i am storing GCM token to my server in database in a key value form {deviceID:GCMToken}

Comment: please prefer the example in question

Comment: @Parth It seems you are supposed to use Instance ID anyway. Please check update.