# Getting Unique device Id in iphone using ionic framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, uniqueidentifier

As I have searched for the same. but, I didn't get proper solution for that as Apple is deprecated this Unique id from iPhone 6 onwards.so how to get the unique id of iPhone in ionic which will remain same in the reinstallation of an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to get a unique device ID.

You can generate it yourself then store it in the device.

Or you can use `UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString`, which is:

> An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor.

It may be possible to persist this ID across reinstallations using KeyChain. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device).

Comment: but if i format the device then this generated id is cleared.

Comment: what if we store it in keychain ? I think keychains data does not wipe out in case of uninstallation

Comment: Umair u are right but if i format the phone then all data is cleared

Comment: @yogi I am afraid then there is no method for keeping the data even after formating the device.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can now do for identification purposes is to use a UUID (*universally unique identifier*) using [$cordovaDevice](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/).

Furthermore, there are [few methods to fetch unique identifiers](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/).