# How to generate device specific unique uuid in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

I want to generate a device specific random uuid which does not change even if the user uninstalls all my apps and reinstall unlike identifierforvendor. How can I achieve this is Swift

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function for creating the UUID:

```
func getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString() -> String {
    var appName: String? = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[(kCFBundleNameKey as? String)] as? String)
    var strApplicationUUID: String = SSKeychain.password(forService: appName, account: "incoding")
    if strApplicationUUID == nil {
        strApplicationUUID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor.uuidString
        SSKeychain.setPassword(strApplicationUUID, forService: appName, account: "incoding")
    }
    return strApplicationUUID
}
```

reference :[How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create random UUID and save it to keychain. Try below link

https://github.com/taka0125/TAKUUID