# Does the 'identifierForVendor.uuidString' changes when app updates with TestFlight builds?

Tags: ios, testflight

Problem Value: identifierForVendor.uuidString

As per the Apple documentation:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

**Scenario:**

1. One of my user has a TestFlight build v1.0.0(0) on his device.
2. He updated the build with v1.0.0(1) on the same device.

Here, this value `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString` got changed. This is so crucial to us to know because we have a logic on app update linked to this value. We assumed this value dont change when user updates the app from TestFlight/AppStore since both are built with AppStore distribution provisioning profile.

Note: User did not delete/uninstall the app. He just updated the build from v1.0.0(0) to v1.0.0(1).

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device

Comment: Thanks Ozgur...I understand that we can get rid of this problem by saving it in the keychain and handling it appropriately. But we have an App Store release next week and I dont want to get into regression on the current build. Please advice.

Comment: I would like to know 'will this issue happens on AppStore builds?' Does anyone came across this situation on TestFlight/AppStore builds? Appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: @Venkat did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Venkat : Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @B.N : You have any answer for this issue, then please share here.

Comment: No, I didn't find an answer to this. Hence I am saving the value in the keychain and using it.