# How to get a unique constant device ID in Swift to count a number of user devices?

Tags: ios, swift, uniqueidentifier, deviceid

There is an app which in a free version of app concrete account can be used only from 2 device. The paid app let use user account from more devices.
Who can I do it?

identifierForVendor can change after reinstall app, so after reinstalling we get a new identifierForVendor and as result a enhance of the devices number.

In iOS 11 we can use DCDevice... what about iOS 9 and 10?

Comment: I would recommend using [this library](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID), in particular: `+(NSString *)uuidForDevice;`. The docs for it say it only changes on System Reset, and hence is better than `identifierForVendor` It is available for iOS 5.0 +.

Comment: You just create your unique id and store it on server side for each user and in keychain on deice, you don't need unique device id. all device id's will reset after device restore

Comment: Your app limitations violate terms of AppStore. AppStore is the one that controls count of devices app can be installed, you shouldn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device)

Comment: @rob180 I saw it, but no... it's not a duplicate.