# How to access one app data from another app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, facebook

How can I access app data from another app (eg. login credentials and user)?

Example: Messenger app can access the Facebook app data like Facebook user data.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

Comment: 1. [keychain](https://medium.com/@anshuraguvansi/keychain-sharing-between-applications-on-ios-af1931468e26) 2. [Apps group](https://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions/#:~:text=App%20Groups%20are%20the%20scheme,of%20their%20normal%20iOS%20sandbox.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: Messenger app can access the Facebook app data like Facebook user data.

**In your Device have UUID based on UUID return user data**

**Api Call return user data based on UUID string**

For your Reference

The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.

[How to preserve identifierForVendor in ios after uninstalling ios app on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device)

Another way also suggest

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups

Answer (score 2):

That can be done with App Groups: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups